# Does the Riemannian connection commute with $(1, 1)$ tensors in the first slot?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds

I know the Riemannian connection commutes with musical isomorphisms, i.e $\sharp\left( \nabla_X \xi \right) = \nabla_X \left( \sharp \xi \right)$, and similarly for $\flat$. My question is: does this generalize for $(1, 1)$ tensors, as in, is it true that given a $(1, 1)$ tensor $F: \Gamma\left( T M \right) \to \Gamma\left( T M \right)$ we have
$$\nabla_{F(X)} Y = F\left(\nabla_X Y \right), \ \forall X, Y \in \Gamma\left( T M \right) \text{?}$$
I think it would be true if $F$ were in the second slot instead of the first one since $\nabla$ commutes with the musical isomorphisms, but from some computations I've been doing I suspect it will (in general) be false in this context. Can anyone think of either a proof or a counterexample? Thanks!

Comment: @TedShifrin Thanks! I think I understood your counterexample. Taking $X = \gamma'$ where $\gamma$ is a geodesic, the left-hand side will be non-zero because we're supposing the orthogonal trajectories are not geodesics and the right-hand side will be zero by the definition of a geodesic.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez I don't know, I didn't try that (I was only working with abstract manifolds and vector fields in my computations). But thanks, that is a very good suggestion that I should have tried, it will most likely not work.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Yeah, I'll do that after this weekend.

Comment: The point is that the left is the directional derivative of $Y$ in the direction of the vector $F(X)$, and the right is a linear transformation of the directional derivative of $Y$ in the direction of the vector $X$. If $F(X) = \ne X$, then there is no reason to believe that the two sides would be equal in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily make a counterexample by taking (on a sphere, say) a geodesic whose orthogonal trajectories are not geodesics. Take $Y=X$ and $F(X)$ the rotation of $X$ through $\pi/2$. Indeed, on the sphere missing two points, you can easily make this global.

Comment: You have to extend locally, but as per my comment, you can define $X$ and $F(X)$ globally away from the poles by taking $X$ the unit tangent to the lines of longitude.